# How to get microtype to work with mathematical minus sign and package lmodern?

Tags: microtype

Using the package microtype by including the line

```
\usepackage{microtype}
```

in the preamble subtly alters the appearance of a typeset document by, amongst other things, letting optically less dense characters, like dashes or punctuations, protrude slightly in the margins. When I use a mathematical minus sign in a document written in the class article, I write it like this:

```
$-$
```

If I include \usepackage{lmodern} in the preamble, the minus sign does not get moved out a little bit if it happens to become the first character of a line, but stays at the same horizontal position as for example an "m" letter. Microtype does work for the plus sign and dashes, including when the plus sign is written in math mode:

```
$+$
```

Does anyone know how to enable microtype also for the mathematical minus sign when using lmodern?

When not using lmodern, the problem can be fixed as suggested by Mico by using \usepackage[protrusion=allmath]{microtype}.

edit: MWE, for which the fix to use \usepackage[protrusion=allmath]{microtype} **does not** work.

Here is some example code that generates the incorrectly placed mathematical minus sign:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[protrusion=allmath]{microtype}
\begin{document}
\section{Test Section}
\label{Test Label}
Test text to reproduce the microtype mathematical minus sign problem that I experienced. I am putting in a few more words to get some text to demonstrate the effect. This is just some text with mathematical minusaaaaaaaaaaaa signs $-$inserted (that was a mathematical minus sign in front of ``inserted'')aaaaa. A +plus sign looks like that. In a longer text that I had, the plus sign looked fine, but the minus sign clearly looked like it was to far in. I am now putting in some more text, just to get one more line to show the look of the left margin.
\end{document}
```

Compiled result (first an enlargement to show the left margin, and then the entire page):

[image: Crop of the compiled page]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried providing the `protrusion=allmath` option to `microtype`?

Comment: I was not aware of that. I tried it (just now), but unfortunately it did not help. It only rendered several warning about microtype not finding protrusion list for font ...

Comment: Aaah, now we're starting to get somewhere: Which (math) fonts do you use? According to the `microtype` manual, protrusion should be enabled for all of the "main" math font packages (Computer Modern (obviously), mathptmx, mathpazo, eulervm, and probably a few more). Please consider editing your question to include a standalone MWE (minimum working example) that generates the problem behavior you're trying to correct.

Comment: I have updated the question with a MWE. I have not specified any particular font, so I assume that the standard font is used. I also noted that the letter spacing does not change correctly if you write text in the math environment (like $In situ$) but it does if you use \emph{In situ} or \textit{In situ}.

Comment: Your using the standard CM fonts indeed. Note that you could surround the `+` by `$` signs without changing the output. The interesting point is: `+` is from the font `cmr10` (no matter if you have `$`s around or not), `-` is from `cmsy10`. It appears that `microtype` just isn't working for the latter font.

Comment: Ah, `protrusion=allmath` does solve the problem for your MWE. It still doesn't make sense that `+` and `-` are treated differently _without_ the `allmath` option. (Ping, @Mico.)

Comment: @HendrikVogt -- good to know that the `protrusion=allmath` option is doing its job... :-)

Comment: Hmm, why did it not work with my big file then... The big file is written in the elsarticle class, and the fix Mico suggested above works whether I compile the MWE as elsarticle or article. It does, however, not work on my big file. I will edit my question to include the preamble of the big file.

Comment: @hjb981: Please try and remove anything from the preamble that does _not_ contribute to the problem. You could do that by removing things piece by piece (and recompiling of course), or by removing 1. the first half of the preamble (+recompile), 2. the 2nd half of the preamble (+recompile), hoping that with either 1. or 2. the problem persists. Then repeat until you get some MWE.

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: I did, and isolated the problem to lmodern.

Comment: @Mico: Now I realized that indeed the problem is with the font lmodern. Is there a way of solving that (other than using a different font)? Can I manually specify the protrusion for the minus sign?

Comment: @hjb981 -- I'm afraid I don't know nearly enough about the `microtype` package's inner workings to be able to suggest how to get it to work with the Latin Modern math fonts (such as `lmm/m/it` (various sizes) and `lmsy/m/n` (various sizes)). My only, admittedly not very constructive, piece of advice for now is not to use the Latin Modern fonts if you need protrusion of math fonts. Going forward, you may want to send an email to the author/maintainer of the microtype package and suggest/request the inclusion of LModern-Math among the font families that are supported by his superb package.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After loading microtype:

```
\DeclareMicrotypeAlias{lmsy}{cmsy}
```

This seems to be an oversight in the microtype package since there is already a line

```
\DeclareMicrotypeAlias{lmr} {cmr}
```

so maybe report this to microtype author...

Comment: That worked. I still get several errors of the kind: I cannot not find a protrusion list for font 'OML/lmm/m/it/10.95' Switching of protrusion for this font on line ... The numbers can also be exchanged for 6, 7, 8, 10, 12 and a few more---I guess that it refers to different sizes. Is there a way to enable microtype for those fonts also?

Comment: I guess `\DeclareMicrotypeAlias{lmm}{cmm}` should do it.

Comment: Yes, it worked. What does that line mean? Does one always write {l _abc_}{c _abc_}, where _abc_ is the name of the font?

Comment: I sent an email to the author of microtype with a short description and a link pointing here.

Comment: @hjb981 it means "use the settings from this font for that one". Since lmodern mostly the same as computer modern, and the fonts are (mostly?) named the same just with interchange of `c` and `l`, it should work ok. However computer modern and lmodern are not identical. Microtype already knows to treat the `\textquotedblleft` et al slightly differently for example, so this quick fix may not be good enough (perhaps this is why it is currently missing from microtype).

Comment: indeed, these two alias declarations were missing in microtype.cfg. I'll add them for the next version (coming "soon"). Thanks for bringing this to my attention.