# Microtype warning with lmodern package and KOMA-script

Tags: fonts, warnings, microtype, sans-serif, latin-modern

With a simple document

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test test test}
\end{document}
```

the `log` file spits out

```
Package microtype Warning: Loading generic settings for font family `lmss'. 
(microtype)                For optimal results, create font-specific settings. 
(microtype)                See the microtype manual for details.
```

This does not happen with the standard `report` class. It seems that KOMA's `scrreprt` (v3.10a) is doing something funny in the chapter-headings and I can not figure out what it is.

If someone could please point me to a solutions I'd appreciate it.

**EDIT**

`\DeclareMicrotype...` does not change the issue

Microtype version is: 2011/08/18 v2.5

**EDIT 2**
`\DeclareMicrotypeAlias{lmss}{cmr}` actually does work. I may have forgotten to remove my log file after adding the command and the error kept coming back.
For details see the accepted answer below

Comment: What version of `microtype` are you using?

Comment: You could try adding `\DeclareMicrotypeAlias{lmss}{cmss}` (not tested by me). See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63615/627

Comment: KOMA sets sectioning titles in sans serif and indeed the warning vanishes if you add `\setkomafont{sectioning}{\normalfont\bfseries}` but reappears when you set something else with `\textsf` (also with the standard classes) so this is not really an issue bound to KOMA.

Comment: @cgnieder Ok, but what can I do now to get rid of this warning? Switching to `\normalfont` is not really an option for me. Actually I would not mind just suppressing the warning as I think it does not have much of an influence. It is just annoying having it in the log every time,

Comment: If you simply want to suppress the message you can load the [`silence`](http://ctan.org/pkg/silence) package and add `\WarningFilter{microtype}{Loading generic settings}` to your preamble.

Comment: @MartinH: You will also get rid of the warnings if you set the protrusion for `lmss` ... or at least pretend that you would: `\SetProtrusion{encoding = T1,family = lmss}{}`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The warning (now: **info, see edit below**) for missing font-specific settings is not a bug but a new feature in the latest `microtype` beta version.

The fallback settings, which are used for fonts unknown to `microtype`, are by nature incomplete, quite conservative and in no way guaranteed to match all possible fonts; therefore, `microtype` now draws the user's attention to this potential source of suboptimal typographic quality.

If you decide against creating settings for the `lmss` font but just want to ignore the warning, there are two possibilities to get rid of it:

- either use existing settings for a different, but sufficiently similar font; in your case, since the design of `lmss` is derived from that of its roman counterpart, `cmr` would be a suitable choice:

  ```
  \DeclareMicrotypeAlias{lmss}{cmr}
  ```
- or disable all warnings that `microtype` issues by passing the option `verbose=silent` (but beware that this would also turn all other warnings into info that then only appears in the log file).

### EDIT:

Because this seems to have created some irritation, the warning from the beta version has been turned into a less alarming info message (which is written to the log file, but not to the console) for the CTAN release.

Comment: +1 for a good explanation of what is going on inside! Maybe you can also comment on what would – typographically – be the preferable workaround in this case? Does aliasing to Computer Modern yield better results than the fallback settings?

Comment: @Daniel in this case I think using the "cmr" settings would be better. I've expanded the answer.

Comment: I tried your first suggestion but it did not remove the warning. For now I went with @cgnieder's idea to use the `silence` package as it appears favourable over `verbose=silent` as I'd like to see other warnings. In my case this warning seems to be related to the chapter headings and I guess it is easy enough to check them for unfavourable spacing and the like

Comment: @Robert Why `cmr` rather than `cmss`?

Comment: @cfr Because settings for `cmss` don't exist either. If they did exist, you would be right, of course.

Comment: @Robert Thanks. I thought it must be something like that but I find it difficult to trace where this stuff gets set. For example, just loading `lmodern` with `microtype` no longer gives these warnings but I'm not sure what has changed where. (I would like to know this in order to offer support for microtypography as an option in `cfr-lm`. Right now it 'seems to work for me' but I don't understand it well enough to risk inflicting it on anyone else, especially since my original solution stopped working at some point.)

Comment: @cfr it's no longer a warning, see edit.

Comment: @Robert Oh, right. Still, `lmodern` no longer produces a complaint in the log file whereas `cfr-lm` does except if I load my personalised version. So `lmodern` or something does something automatically which I can't trace so far.

Comment: @cfr Hm, I do get a complaint with the sans font of `lmodern`. (not with the roman font, since `microtype.cfg` contains the line `\DeclareMicrotypeAlias{lmr}{cmr}`.) You probably need to add these alias declarations to `cfr-lm`, too.

Comment: @Robert I should probably experiment a bit more. Maybe I didn't trigger the sf warning for some reason. Is it enough to declare the alias or is there more to it than that? Right now I just do that for each font family but I've not been sure that's right.

Comment: @cfr Yes, declaring aliases for each font family should be all you'd have to do. (Note that the alias translation will only be applied once, so you should always link to existing settings, i.e. `clm -> cmr` and `clmj -> cmr`, not `clmj -> clm` and `clm -> cmr`.)

Comment: @Robert Thanks. That's what I'm doing. I'm just looping through the families, basically. (So it is less typing to alias them all to the same thing anyway!) That's very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Too long for an comment:

I tried your given MWE (only added `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` and compiled it **without any error or warning** on my actual MiKTeX version 2.9 distribution.

Here the used files `\listfiles`reported:

```
 *File List*
scrreprt.cls    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script document class (report)
scrkbase.sty    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent basics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent basics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2012/06/15 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2012/04/04 v3.10b KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize11pt.clo    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
typearea.sty    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (type area)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
inputenc.sty    2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
microtype.sty    2010/01/10 v2.4 Micro-typography with pdfTeX (RS)
microtype.cfg    2010/01/10 v2.4 microtype main configuration file (RS)
 lmodern.sty    2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
   t1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
  mt-cmr.cfg    2009/11/09 v2.0 microtype config. file: Computer Modern Roman (RS)
  t1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
```

With documentclass `report` no errors or warnings.

As you can see my `microtype` version is 2.4 and I have no error or warning. So the change from version 2.4 to 2.5 causes the mentioned error/warning.

Comment: The OP uses the beta version of microtype 2.5. Believe me, you also will get the warning with it.

Comment: @Speravir: I'm sure, I will. But my answer just documented, that teh error comes from the new version of `microtype` and should be fixed there.

Comment: Thanks for testing. It would be interesting to know what change caused this warning. Most of microtype's configuration is a bit over my head...